# Positioning pdf_tex in Latex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, positioning, input

I want to get a pdf_tex file between two paragraphs of text. But I only know the `\input` command for the embedding of the file and the `\input` command always places the picture on a new page. Is there a different command that doesn't do this or is there some way to fix it? Code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT  
\begin{figure}  
\centering
\input{blub.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\begin{figure}[htbp]`? Or maybe disable floating with `\begin{figure}[H]`.

Comment: @Daniel Stich- thanks. it got a little better through \begin{figure}[H]. Now its at the right position ( between the to praragraphs)^^ but latex still wants this picture to be on a new page :/

Comment: Okay so i just figured out the problem myself. The size of my picture was too big.  My drawing was small. But the size of the picture was that of an A4 page. So latex hat no other option then displaying it on a new page. Just shrinking the picture to the right size solved this problem :^)

Comment: `\input` always appears exactly where you place it. It is the `figure` environment that moves its content (it has no other purpose) you should only use `figure` to specify content as a float that may be inserted at a different place.

Answer (score 0):

- Solved by OP in comments.
- Picture size was too big which caused LaTeX to put it on the next page.